# Roman number in chapter header but not in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters, roman-numerals

I need roman numbers for chapters header but in the table of contents I still want arabic numbers for the chapter. Is it possible?

For the chapter header I used this tag:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ \Roman{chapter}}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Is the `\ ` really necessary there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code, the `\renewcommand` you're using now is not needed (and should in fact be omitted to obtain arabic numbers in the table of contents).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

The code works by patching specifically the command LaTeX uses internally to typeset the chapter title, while leaving the entry to the table of contents intact.